# Process description for Windows XP Home Edition

Tags: windows-xp, process, task-manager

In my Windows XP Home Edition, there is no desciption for the processes in the task manager.

For example, all the services seem to appear with the same-name processes "SVCHOST.EXE". But I want to find out the one that use most of the CPU, however there is no more description I can find in task manager.

I saw in this [link](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/svchost.htm), one can use tasklist for Windows XP Professional Edition. BUt how to accomplish the same thing for Home edition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go have a look at Process Explorer from [SysInternals](http://www.sysinternals.com). It will show you (by hovering over each process) which services are running, which will help you narrow it down.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the advice in the link that you posted and use [process explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/sysinternals/utilities/ProcessExplorer.mspx) maybe?
It really is a good application.

EDIT: If you'd rather use tasklist itself, you can download it [here](http://www.computerhope.com/download/winxp.htm).